# What are the technical differences between Ubuntu and Debian?

Tags: package-management, debian, embedded-system

I understand the philosophical differences, and things like release cycle, stability, etc. But on a more technical level, what's different between the OSes themselves? I know they use different package repos, for instance, as well as minor things like /etc/os-release. Is there anything else?

To rephrase my question, what would need to change in order to make a Debian system into an Ubuntu system?

A bit broader context, I'm working with embedded systems, and Ubuntu has better support for one of the packages I need to use. Using multistrap to generate a Debian rootfs won't let me use it, but if I switch out the repos for the Ubuntu ones, and get all the packages I need from the Ubuntu repos, everything works. I'm trying to figure out if I generated an Ubuntu root filesystem, or just a Debian rootfs with Ubuntu repos and packages.

Comment: Mixing Debian and Ubuntu is called a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian). That's not a good thing.

Comment: Snap packages and the completely non-Debian (snap-only) Ubuntu Core are designed for embedded system use.

Comment: @user535733 I'm not mixing Debian and Ubuntu repos, I never have the Debian repos at all, not even on initial installation. Is that still a frankendebian? That page says the problem is that packages will get upgraded to incompatible versions, but I'd assume that if I'm getting *everything* from the Ubuntu repos, it should be fine, right? Also I'm against snap for moral reasons as well as that I've had bad experiences with them, so snaps and Ubuntu core are probably out of the picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Key differences:

- Branding
- Some default settings to ensure packages are safe-by-default.
- Some default settings to ensure packages don't require advanced configuration to "just work" for most new/unskilled users.
- Some package choices and the addition of snap packages (like Firefox) in the stock install.
- Software versions, since the release dates of Ubuntu and Debian often do not align.

Most of these are not big differences from stock Debian. Ubuntu generally tries to keep the delta with upstream Debian small (Small = Maintainable).

There is no safe, tested, supported path to "*make a Debian system into an Ubuntu system*" (nor the reverse). In theory, you could get close using both an apt dist-upgrade AND replacement of all the changed settings. But since it's untested and unsupported, all the pain points you encounter on that path are your own to solve.